# XP_CMDSHELL bcp error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am executing the XP_CMDSHELL as below:

```
Exec XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "Select OrderID, OrderDate, OrderDesc from DB.dbo.Order" queryout C:\Orderfile.txt -k -t \t -c -Slocalhost -T'
```

I got the following error:

"Unable to open BCP host datafile."

I looked at the c:\ drive and there is a file Orderfile.txt exist. ANd i have not opened the file or any other program doesn't not the file. But still I am getting this error.

Anyone have any idea why I am getting this error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two issues:

- XP_CMDSHELL uses the SQL Server service account credentials for filesystem (and other) access. The service account won't have permissions on the root of C: and it doesn't matter if *you* can see it
- SQL Server is on a server somewhere (that is, isn't a local install) and you are trying to access your local C: drive. SQL Server can't see this of course...

Comment: Thank You, I created the file in the server and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

there should be full permission on drive.
file is create automatically.
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "Select * From [test].[dbo].[Customer]" QUERYOUT C:\Backup\customer123.txt -S HP-PC -T -c'

[image]